# How do I extract characters in a specific position from an input string?

Tags: c++, string

For my homework project I'm expected to create a program that asks the user their favorite city and which character they would like to display. The user inputs a number representing the position of the character within the city they would like to display, and the program is supposed to display the letter at this position.

We have not yet learned how to extract characters from a string, but this part of our project is supposed to show that we can properly google to find solutions for our coding. I have found a void function that would extract the character from a specific position for me, but am entirely lost on how to use it. I've tried several different methods and typed out every way I could possibly think to implement this function and it has not worked.

I've tried copying the example code I found online exactly as is (first example found at this address: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-at-in-cpp/) but even the example would not run in visual studio 2017.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void at(string);
int main()
{
    //variables for favorite city & display character
    string favCity;
    int dispChar;
        //asking user for favorite city
        cout << "Input your favorite city: ";
        cin >> favCity;
        cout << "Which character would you like to display: ";
        cin >> dispChar;
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "The user entered: " << favCity << endl;
        cout << "The character at position " << dispChar << " is: " << at();

}
```

The expected result is that the computer will display "The character at position (dispChar) is: (whatever letter is at the user input position dispChar)"

EX: `"The character at position 2 is: e` //If the user input the city Detroit

I get the error that `at` is undefined, when I tried using `str.at();` I would get `str` is undefined, etc.

Comment: Where is the implementation of `at` function?

Comment: Due to `void at(string);` declaration, you need to pass a string into the `at` function, but you don't: `cout << "The character at position " << dispChar << " is: " << at();`

Comment: @user3365922 when I change it to `at(favCity);` the last `<<` in my last `cout` statement is underlined and i get the following error:

`C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: @mrazimi at the end of my last `cout` statement it says `at();` but i have since changed this to `at(favCity);` and the program still will not run giving me an error with the `<<` directly before the at function

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of using an external function in order to extract a character from a string by its index. [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) itself implements an `std::string::at` function and also overloaded `[]` operator.

So two ways for doing that:

1.

```cpp
cout << "The character at position " << dispChar << " is: " << favCity.at(dispChar);
```

2.

```cpp
cout << "The character at position " << dispChar << " is: " << favCity[dispChar];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this solution worked perfectly, really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Liv Welcome. Suggesting you to read more about `std:: string`, functions in C++ and their declaration and definition, etc. Also you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

std::string::at can be used to extract characters by characters from a given string.
`char& string::at (size_type idx)`

string::at function returns the character at the specific position(idx). You can directly use string::at as you have included  class.[Learn More Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-at-in-cpp/)

So, in your solution you declared `void at(string);` therefore you need to define it too.
I have made some changes in your code I think that should do it.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void extract_char(string str, int pos)
{
    cout<<str.at(pos);
}
int main(void)
{
    int dispChar;
    string favCity;
    cout<<"Input your favorite city: ";
    cin>>favCity;
    cout<<"Which position would you like to extract the character from(0 to size of city): ";
    cin>>dispChar;
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"The user entered: "<<favCity<<endl;
    extract_char(favCity, dispChar-1);
    /*
                  OR
        cout<<"The character at position "<<dispChar<<" is: "<<favCity.at(dispChar-1);
    */
    return 0;
}
```